# scapy sniffed udp packets can not be received after sending to another host

Tags: python, sockets, networking, scapy, packet

I am trying to send `udp` packets sniffed by `scapy` to another host. The host address is reachable through my default gateway.

In the host I listen to the destination port `10000` by `tcpdump`, **but the packets are not received.**

My code is this:

```py
from scapy.all import *

class Des:
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.port = port

def send_packets(port):
    des = Des(port)
    def get_pack(packet):
        pkt = packet.copy()
        pkt['IP'].dst= "192.168.20.111" # address of the destination host
        pkt['IP'].src = "192.168.12.111" # address of my system
        pkt['UDP'].dport = des.port
        pkt['Ethernet'].dst = dst_mac
        pkt['Ethernet'].src = src_mac
        send(pkt)
    return get_pack

sniff(filter = 'udp and port 50000', prn = send_packets(10000))
```

If I send the packets to another host `192.168.12.112` in my network the problem still exists. In this scenario if I replace the `send` line with the following line, these packets **will be received in the destination!**

```py
send(IP(dst='192.168.12.112')/UDP(dport=10000))
```

While replacing it with the following line, results in **no receiving  packets in host `192.168.20.111`**.

```py
send(IP(dst='192.168.20.111')/UDP(dport=10000))
```

I searched for the problem but found no result. The firewall in the both side is disabled and scapy has the routing path as the following output.

```py
>>> conf.route
Network         Netmask         Gateway         Iface           Output IP
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         192.168.12.1    vr0             192.168.12.111
192.168.12.0    255.255.255.0   0.0.0.0         vr0             192.168.12.111
```

Furthermore, `tcpdump` on my output interface shows that when using

```py
send(IP(dst='ANY_DST)/UDP(dport=ANY_PORT))
```

the packets are going out, but when I send the sniffed packets, they don't!

**Where did I go wrong?**
May the problem be with the changed packets? They are `RTP` packets containing payload.

I am very new to python and scapy. Any help can be a light to move in the right direction. Thanks for your time.

My OS is `FreeBSD9.2` and i am using `python 2.7` and `scapy (2.2.0)`.

Comment: "The host address is reachable through my default gateway": You've verified that with a `ping`? Does a `tracert` to it show anything weird?

Comment: There is noting weird to me. In the scapy I use `traceroute('192.168.20.111')` and the output shows: the first step is my `default gateway` and the second is `192.168.20.111`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I replace the send line with the following line, these packets will
> be received in the destination!
>
> send(IP(dst='192.168.12.112')/UDP(dport=10000))

After debugging the code and checking the source of scapy, I found the reason of the above problem. When I call `send(pkt)`, From class `L3dnetSocket` following function is called.

```py
        def send(self, x):
            iff,a,gw  = x.route()
            # Rest of the code is ignored here
```

Here  object `x` is of `class Packet` and its `route` function always returns `None` for `gateway`! So the packet will be send in layer 2.

```py
    def route(self):
        return (None,None,None)
```

While when I call `send(IP(dst='192.168.12.112')/UDP(dport=10000))`, type of object `x` is `class IP` that it's `route` function returns the correct `gateway`.

```py
    def route(self):
        dst = self.dst
        if isinstance(dst,Gen):
            dst = iter(dst).next()
        return conf.route.route(dst)
```

**Finally, I changed my code as the following and it works correctly :)**

```py
def send_packet(port):
    des = Des(port)
    def get_pack(packet):
        udp = UDP()
        udp.sport = packet[UDP].sport
        udp.dport = des.port
        udp.len = packet[UDP].len

        ip = IP()
        ip.version = packet[IP].version
        ip.tos = packet[IP].tos
        ip.len = packet[IP].len
        ip.id = packet[IP].id
        ip.flags = packet[IP].flags
        ip.frag = packet[IP].frag
        ip.ttl = packet[IP].ttl
        ip.proto = packet[IP].proto
        ip.dst = '192.168.12.112'

        payload = packet[Raw].load

        pkt = ip/udp/payload
        pkt = pkt.__class__(bytes(pkt))

        send(pkt)

    return get_pack
```

Furthermore, the reason that the packets were not received in my reachable networks, was from my network :)